# How to filter out records between two dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to apply join between two tables to get the desirable result. Can you please help me how to do this?

Example:

df1:

```
kol_id   jnj_id   kol_full_nm         foc_area_id   thrc_cd  thrc_nm  
101152  7124166 Constance Ann Benson      1          VIR       VIR
251489  7822721 Mariam S Aziz             1          VIR       VIR
100856  7356682 William Rodney Short      1          VIR       VIR
```

df2:

```
kol_id     jnj_id     thrc_nm
101152     7124166    VIR
```

desirable result:

df_final :

```
kol_id   jnj_id   kol_full_nm         foc_area_id   thrc_cd  thrc_nm  
101152  7124166 Constance Ann Benson      1          VIR       VIR
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 
df_3=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['kol_id','jnj_id'],how='inner')
```

Replace inner with left,right,outer depending on type of join required.